# jQuery clone(): original content's radio button clicking show/hide not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm cloning HTML code with jQuery and append it to div after appending the original content is broken, both radio buttons are getting `unchecked`, so how can I solve this issue ?

Could you help me ?

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x2dak6u1/)

> HTML

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <button>clone</button>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-header">
                <label for="one">one</label>
                <input type="radio" class="content-disable-enable" id="one" name="radio" checked>
            </div>
            <div class="content-body">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-header">
                <label for="two">two</label>
                <input type="radio" class="content-disable-enable" id="two" name="radio">
            </div>
            <div class="content-body">
                <input type="text" class="form-control disabled">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> JS

```
$('.content-disable-enable').click(function () {
    $('.content-disable-enable').closest('.content').find('.content-body').find('.form-control').addClass('disabled');
    $(this).closest('.content').find('.content-body').find('.form-control').removeClass('disabled');
});

$('button').click(function () {
    var inputFroupClone = $('.input-group:first-of-type').clone();
    $('.contentWrapper').append(inputFroupClone);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of things you have missed in your code. Simply doing clone will broke the radio button functionality. Because the radio buttons will have same name when you clone it. Also if you want deep clone like you need to have same click events then you have to do with true like `clone(true)`. After you clone, you have to change the name of the radio buttons. So that it will not affect the other radio button functionalities.

In the second part you are disabling the alternate textbox using the common css classname. This will also affect the cloning textboxes. You have to change that logic also. Look at my code, I have done the changes as per the above scenarios.

```
  var count = 1;
  $('.content-disable-enable').click(function () {
       $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.content').find('.content-body').find('.form-control').addClass('disabled');
       $(this).closest('.content').find('.content-body').find('.form-control').removeClass('disabled');
  });

  $('button').click(function () {
     count = count + 1;
     var inputFroupClone = $('.input-group:first-of-type').clone(true);
     finalClone = inputFroupClone.find('input[type=radio]').attr('name','test'+count).find('input[type=text]').attr('name','test'+count);
     $('.contentWrapper').append(inputFroupClone);
  });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/x2dak6u1/3/)

Comment: Thanks for answering in my question @SureshPonnukalai `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.content')`  but in my case I can't use this code, i need to use `$(this).closest('.content')` because in some case my `.content` parent is third level, in some case it in second level, I'm trying to change it in your code to closest but not work, maybe you know the reason ?

Comment: :) you can use closest instead of parent. I have updated my answer and fidddle.

Comment: Thank you for answer @SureshPonnukalai .

Comment: please change `.input-form` to `.input-group` in your code.

Comment: typo mistake. I have changed now.